# Do I need to define huge VPC subnets in order to run many Lambda functions in parallel?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, vpc

I read that each AWS Lambda invocation gets it's own private IP (when running in VPC).
Does this mean that if I want 50,000 Lambdas running in parallel I need it to run in a VPC subnet with 50,000 available private IPs?

Comment: If you're at the scale of wanting to run 500k Lambda functions simultaneously, I'd expect you to have at least a business-level support relationship with AWS. That would give you access to support engineers who can help you engage the Lambda team. Even if you only subscribe to business-level support for a month in order to work through this challenge, it might be worthwhile.

Comment: Also note that the largest VPC size is /16 which is 65,536 total IPv4 addresses (and you need to subtract 5 reserved addresses).

Comment: Why are you running your Lambda inside VPC?

Comment: To use private resources such as RDS (without the overhead of SSL and firewall)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: Yes.

If you want to run 50000 concurrent lambdas inside VPC, you will need more than 50000 IP Addresses as some IP Addresses may not get released right after the end of lambda execution.

There is a soft limit of running 1000 lambdas per account running concurrently. It is a soft limit so you can always submit a ticket and ask AWS to raise it but I doubt they will raise it to 50000.

### Update

This is no longer true. Please refer to the answer by @luk2302.

Comment: Can I overcome this limit by not running the lambdas in a VPC?

Comment: 1000 concurrent lambda limitation applies regardless where your lambda is running (Inside or outside VPC). You will need to raise a ticket and ask AWS to raise it.

Comment: The correct answer should be the one below.

Comment: @Asdfg thanks for the update, I am actually quite surprised this was the case once, seems to defeat the purpose and advantages of lambdas in large parts. Nice trip down AWS history lane.

Answer (score 8):

Short (updated) answer: **No**. You do not need a large VPC.

The accepted answer was correct for some time. However back in 2019 AWS changed how Lambdas work within VPCs: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/announcing-improved-vpc-networking-for-aws-lambda-functions/

Since then each distinct 'subnet + security group' combination now only needs **one IP** / one ENI **within your VPC** and that ENI is shared across all execution environments / lambda invocations across all different lambda functions. So even if you have 100 lambda functions within your VPC and 10k concurrent invocations you only need one IP as long as the lambdas are configured similarly.