# How many Lambda functions can be created in a VPC to connect to EFS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc, amazon-efs

I need to create lambda functions that mount an AWS EFS(Elastic File System).
It seems to be mandatory to create a VPC in order to mount EFS with Lambda.
AWS has a [maximum VPC size](https://aws.amazon.com/vpc/faqs/) of /16 (65,536 IPs).
[Network interfaces](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/amazon-vpc-limits.html) per Region -> 5,000.
If I understand this right, does this also mean that I can only create ~5000 lambda functions that can mount the EFS resource?

The project that I am working on requires having the ability to be able to create any number of lambda functions to mount the EFS resource. So the question is how can we overcome this limit? Understandably, creating unlimited lambda functions may not be possible in a VPC, but is there a way to be able to create way more lambda functions to mount the EFS? Also if yes, how many lambda functions can be created that can mount the same EFS resource?

Also, currently AWS lambda only supports [dual-stack subnets](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/12/aws-lambda-ipv6-endpoints-inbound-connections/). It does not seem to support ipv6-only subnets.

Comment: The lambda service does only need one IP / network interface per security-group/subnet combination. Regardless of functions or function executions. Are you looking at actually creating 5000 different lambda functions or having 5000 executions of the same lambda? You can just look at the available IP addresses in your VPC, create 10 lambdas and see by how much the number of available addresses changes.

Comment: Are these multiple _different_ AWS Lambda functions, or are you wanting to allow multiple parallel executions of a _single_ Lambda function? There is a default limit of 1000 parallel executions of a single Lambda function -- are you likely to have that many running simultaneously?

Comment: @luk2302 - 'You can just look at the available IP addresses in your VPC,' - it'd be great if  you could advise where it is possible to see that information

Comment: @Elliveny in the VPC console -> Subnets -> "available IPv4 addresses" - the available IPs in the subnet, not the VPC, but still fits what would be needed here.

Comment: No, not parallel 5000 executions of a single lambda. I actually meant creating new lambda functions. As @luk2302 mentioned I did try creating 10 lambdas and observing the available addresses in the subnet. The lambda service used only one IP and network interface per security-group/subnet combination. So, no problems at all now for my use case. Thanks, appreciate the help!

Comment: @dhruvparekh12 https://stackoverflow.com/a/71645461/2442804 for a bit more detail and docs link.